# What causes the table cells to be displayed at random/unknown pattern?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, uitableview, xcode4

The app I'm creating launches with a table view. I can immediately add a new information, save the information to a plist, and reload the view. The new cell and its data shows up at the bottom. When I re-run the app however, it re-orders the order I originally saw them.

The titles of the cell are stored in a variable called `countdowns` and the descriptions are stored in `countdown_info`. I then use these variables and store them as a dictionary in the plist.

Here's an example that has the same result every time. The following is the table view as it would appear if I had just added 4 new cells:

```
**[CODE 1]**
Countdown 1
  Description 1
Countdown 2
  Description 2
Countdown 3
  Description 3
Countdown 4
  Description 4
```

However, when the app re-runs/re-builds, the app opens to this:

```
**[View After Re-Run]**
Countdown 4
  Description 4
Countdown 1
  Description 1
Countdown 3
  Description 3
Countdown 2
  Description 2
```

Some NSLogs I've added reveal the table from the file are saved as [Code 1], and that indexPath.row on the table view increase from 0-3, but for some reason, the view reorganizes with a different pattern.

What is the cause of this? Thanks!

*Code from cellRowAtIndexPath*

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
}

ClockworkAppDelegate *dataCenter = (ClockworkAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

cell.textLabel.text = [[dataCenter countdowns] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[dataCenter countdown_info] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSDictionaries are [unordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295459/are-keys-and-values-in-an-nsdictionary-ordered), so you are probably losing the ordering when saving to NSUserDefaults. You'll have to store the order somehow as well. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376090/nsdictionary-with-ordered-keys) for some ideas.

Comment: The thread you linked to gave me some great tips! It seems I just needed an Enumerator to help re-organize the data. Thanks!