# iOS - NSDictionary - Reading plist file

Tags: ios, plist, nsdictionary

I've a plist file which has a menu to be shown (related to a restaurant)
I added the dictionary items in the order they have to be shown.
But when I'm reading the plist file into NSDictionary, the same order in plist is not being maintained. Why? How should I display it in the same order as that in the plist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are keys and values in an NSDictionary ordered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295459/are-keys-and-values-in-an-nsdictionary-ordered)

Comment: I'm not talking about the sorting for key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of dictionary, we've to create nsarray which will read same and so we can display the same.