# NSDictionary not returns keys as it arranged while inserting data?

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I have set up a NSDictionary and And I want its keys as its arranged.But When I print log of dictionary,its allkeys and allkeys sorted it gives me different output.Any way I can get NSDictionary keys as I have arranged it.My code is as follows:-

```
titleDics=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[titleDics setObject:@"Exchange" forKey:@"exchange"];
[titleDics setObject:@"Order No" forKey:@"nestordernumber"];
[titleDics setObject:@"Transaction Type" forKey:@"transactiontype"];
[titleDics setObject:@"Symbol Name" forKey:@"symbolname"];
[titleDics setObject:@"Price to fill" forKey:@"pricetofill"];
[titleDics setObject:@"Exchange Order ID" forKey:@"exchangeorderid"];
[titleDics setObject:@"Status" forKey:@"status"];
[titleDics setObject:@"Price Type" forKey:@"pricetype"];
[titleDics setObject:@"Duration" forKey:@"duration"];
[titleDics setObject:@"Product Code" forKey:@"productcode"];
[titleDics setObject:@"Script Name" forKey:@"scripname"];

NSLog(@"Title Dictioanry is %@",titleDics);

NSLog(@"Title dics keys are %@",[titleDics allKeys]);

NSLog(@"Title dics sorted keys are %@",[[titleDics allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]);
```

output is :-----

```
2013-05-30 12:51:43.924 MobileTrading[1676:11303] Title Dictioanry is {
duration = Duration;
exchange = Exchange;
exchangeorderid = "Exchange Order ID";
nestordernumber = "Order No";
pricetofill = "Price to fill";
pricetype = "Price Type";
productcode = "Product Code";
scripname = "Script Name";
status = Status;
symbolname = "Symbol Name";
transactiontype = "Transaction Type";
}
2013-05-30 12:51:43.924 MobileTrading[1676:11303] Title dics keys are (
    nestordernumber,
    productcode,
    symbolname,
    pricetype,
    exchange,
    exchangeorderid,
    pricetofill,
    scripname,
    status,
    duration,
    transactiontype
)
2013-05-30 12:51:43.924 MobileTrading[1676:11303] Title dics sorted keys are (
    duration,
    exchange,
    exchangeorderid,
    nestordernumber,
    pricetofill,
    pricetype,
    productcode,
    scripname,
    status,
    symbolname,
    transactiontype
)
```

I want that keys in the order I have setted to NSDictionary i.e;

```
exchange,
nestordernumber,
transactiontype,
symbolname,
pricetofill,
exchangeorderid,
status,
pricetype,
duration,
productcode,
scripname,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `NSMutableDictionary` always returns keys in a disordered fashion.

If you really want to maintain order then you need to do some trick. Like...

**1)** Add `01, 02 ,03` **Serial Numbers** before your `Keys` to sort them in the order you want to put it.

**2) Trim** the first two characters of the String and use it.

Answer (score 0):

This link explains storing the keys of the required dictionary in a separate array you want and then use them accordingly

[Are keys and values in an NSDictionary ordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295459/are-keys-and-values-in-an-nsdictionary-ordered)