# Is it safe to assume that the ordering of the same set of keys in two different NSMutableDictionaries is the same?

Tags: objective-c, json, serialization, foundation

I have complex data structure, mostly made up of NSDictionaries, generated by NSJSONSerialization reading a large JSON file. Now, the dictionaries in such structure, use all the same keys. Would it be safe to assume that the ordering of the keys is the same in all dictionaries? My gut would tell me so, but it really depends on the implementation, I guess.

Cheers,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are keys and values in an NSDictionary ordered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295459/are-keys-and-values-in-an-nsdictionary-ordered)

Answer (score 0):

My gut would say no. What I don't know is if there is a type of "order by" method that you could call. You may want to store keys in an array, then use that for your ordering to pull from the dictionary.

Look here as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1295472/546237