# swift returning wrong index of dictionary

Tags: swift, swift2, nsdictionary

I have this simple code :

```
var dic = [25:"first" , 35 : "second"  , 55 : "third"]
let firstKey = Array(dic.keys)[0] // or .first
print (firstKey)
```

I guess it suppose to return `25`  because the first key at the first index of the dictionary if 25 .But strangely it's returning 35 .

What's wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: It's normal, it is not an ordered set of datas.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295459/are-keys-and-values-in-an-nsdictionary-ordered

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered key-value representation. So it is normal not to print first value of the dictionary.

Comment: What do you want to achieve . you first know the basic difference between the dictionary and array and ordered dic

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let firstKey = Array(dic.keys).sort()[0]
```

Comment: I don't want to change the indexes. I want key and value at the specific index.Doesn't your code messing with indexes ?

Comment: @sali you no not *have* indices in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

From [Swift Doc](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/type/Dictionary/):

> **Dictionary**
>
> A hash-based mapping from Key to Value instances. Also a collection of key-value pairs with **no defined ordering**

So by creating a `Dictionary` with a dictionary literal it is very likely that the ordering is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an assumption that a dictionary is ordered, it is not. See the [Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) section of the Swift Programming Language Guide. What does this mean? It mean's that there is **no guarantee** that the values or keys are stored in the order you create them. The only guarantee you have is that accessing a value by it's key will return that value.

If you require your keys to be accessed in a given order it is up to you to provide that ability.

If you look at the [Swift Standard Library Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Dictionary_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structp/Dictionary/s:vVSs10Dictionary4keysGVSs17LazyMapCollectionGS_q_q0__q__) it documents what methods we can use on a dictionary.

You have the following properties and functions for working with indexes with dictionaries.

Properties:

```
startIndex 
endIndex
```

Functions

```
func indexForKey(_ key: Key) -> DictionaryIndex<Key, Value>?
func removeAtIndex(_ index: DictionaryIndex<Key, Value>) -> (Key, Value)
```

Dictionaries also conform to the [indexable protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Indexable_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:PSs9Indexable).

> Collection Types
>
> Swift provides three primary collection types, known
>   as arrays, sets, and dictionaries, for storing collections of values.
>   Arrays are ordered collections of values. Sets are unordered
>   collections of unique values. **Dictionaries are unordered collections**
>   of key-value associations.